# Page numbering on inputed files and partial amount pages

Tags: page-numbering

I try to compile several `.tex` in a main document, so i use the package `subfiles`.
I want to display for each inputed file the page number of the current page relatively to the inputed file, and also to display the total pages of this inputed file on each its page ; and this for all the inputed files.
I'm near to sucess but ...
I use a local counter for the number of page, and several counters for the total page amount of each inputed file (using the package `totcount`).

I have simplified the code, so here I have one main file "main-file.tex", and 3 folders "Ch1", "Ch2", and "Ch3", the first containing the file "Ch1-2nde.tex", the second containing the file "Ch2-2nde.tex", and the last the file "Ch3-2nde.tex".
Here is the code I use for main-file.tex :

```
    \documentclass[s,onecolumn]{article}
    \RequirePackage[a4paper, top=0.5cm, bottom=1.6cm, left=0.7cm , right=0.7cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \RequirePackage{multido}
    \usepackage{subfiles}
    \RequirePackage{totcount}

    \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \makeatletter
    \let\org@subfile\subfile
    \renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{%
        \filename@parse{#1}% LaTeX's file name parser
        \expandafter
        \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area}}%
        \org@subfile{#1}%
        \newpage %ajout ici pour sauter automatiquement une page entre
    }
    \makeatother

    \newcounter{localPage}
    \newcounter{AuxCounter} 
    \renewcommand{\theAuxCounter}{\roman{AuxCounter}}
    %to create counter "compteurChi" "compteurChii" ..., and \roman because no
    %number is supported as a counter name.

    \newcommand{\entetecours}[1]
    {
        \setcounter{localPage}{0}

        \begin{center} 
            {\textbf{\huge Chapitre #1}}
        \end{center}

        \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Page \thepage / \pageref{LastPage} }}
        \setcounter{AuxCounter}{#1}
        \fancyfoot[L]{Chap#1
            {\addtocounter{compteurCh\theAuxCounter}{1}
            \addtocounter{localPage}{1}
            \fbox{\bfseries \thelocalPage} / \total{compteurCh\theAuxCounter}}
            }
    }

    \begin{document}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{3}{%
        \setcounter{AuxCounter}{\i}
        \newcounter{compteurCh\theAuxCounter}
        \regtotcounter{compteurCh\theAuxCounter}
    }

    \multido{\i=1+1}{3}{\subfile{Ch\i/Ch\i-2nde}}
    \end{document}
```

Here the code in Ch1-2nde.tex :

```
    \entetecours{1}
    Ch1 first page
    \newpage
    Ch1 second page
    \newpage
    Ch1 third page
```

The code in Ch2-2nde.tex :

```
    \entetecours{2}
    Ch2 first page
    \newpage
    Ch2 second page
    \newpage
    Ch2 third page
```

The code in Ch3-2nde.tex :

```
    \entetecours{3}
    Ch3 first page
    \newpage
    Ch3 second page
    \newpage
    Ch3 third page
```

So, The problem is even if I compile two times, there is still "??" left at the bottom left side for the two first inputed files (the counter value of compteurChi and compteurChii are not present in the .aux file ... And I don't know why).

Please, some help ^^.

Comment: The `compteurCh` counters are defined after `\begin{document}`, this screws the totcount system up

Comment: If I put the block : `\multido{\i=1+1}{3}{%
         \setcounter{AuxCounter}{\i}
         \newcounter{compteurCh\theAuxCounter}
         \regtotcounter{compteurCh\theAuxCounter}
        }`
before the `\begin{document}` nothing change, it stays as before.

Comment: `\newcounter` should be used in the preamble only

Comment: by writing `\setcounter{AuxCounter}{1}
 \newcounter{compteurChi}
 \regtotcounter{compteurChi}
 \newcounter{compteurChii}
 \regtotcounter{compteurChii}
 \newcounter{compteurChiii}
 \regtotcounter{compteurChiii}` in the preamble, it worked. So the problem comes from the loop .... Do you know how to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: math45: Loops with command definitions (which is true for `\newcounter` too) are always tricky, due to grouping effects

Comment: I've transfered this post on a more specific post : [here : Loop to create new counters][1]


  [1]: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245113/loop-to-create-new-counters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245113/loop-to-create-new-counters)