# How to get the number of beamer's frames inside a personal environment?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, numbering, counters

Suppose I have a `beamer` presentation with some contiguous frames containing a "special content" that are inside a `specialcontent` environment. I'd like to *introduce* this special content with a frame that display both:

- the numbers of "special" frames,
- the frame (not page) number of the last "special frame,

as in the MCE below (`<total number of frames>` and `<number of last frame of the special content>`).

How could I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\newenvironment{specialcontent}{%
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Special content}
    The following special content:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item has <total number of frames> frames,
    \item ends frame \# <number of last frame of the special content>.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
}{%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo bar}
  Foo\pause{} bar.
\end{frame}

\begin{specialcontent}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Foo bar (special content)}
    Foo\pause{} bar.
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Foo bar (special content)}
    Foo\pause{} bar.
  \end{frame}

\end{specialcontent}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo bar}
  Foo\pause{} bar.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can the "specialcontent" be a section?

Comment: @samcarter No, sorry :)

Comment: Too bad, that would have been easy :)

Comment: @samcarter Maybe it would be useful to explain your solution in case of section instead of environment.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308343/how-to-create-mini-sections-mini-subsections-and-mini-frames-in-beamer-presenta/313579#313579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `totcount` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{endspecial}
\newcounter{startspecial}
\regtotcounter{endspecial}


\newenvironment{specialcontent}{%
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Special content}
    The following special content:
    \begin{itemize}
    \setcounter{startspecial}{\totvalue{endspecial}}
    \addtocounter{startspecial}{1}
    \addtocounter{startspecial}{-\insertframenumber}
    \item has \thestartspecial  <total number of frames> frames,
    \item ends frame \total{endspecial} <number of last frame of the special content>.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
}{%
  \setcounter{endspecial}{\insertframenumber}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo bar}
  Foo\pause{} bar.
\end{frame}

\begin{specialcontent}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Foo bar (special content)}
    Foo\pause{} bar.
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Foo bar (special content)}
    Foo\pause{} bar.
  \end{frame}

\end{specialcontent}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo bar}
  Foo\pause{} bar.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your comments, I realized the package I was looking for was indeed `totcount`. Nicely, quickly and efficiently done, as usual :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Thanks a lot for your kind words!

Comment: If I'm right, `\addtocounter{startspecial}{1}` should be removed, otherwise the numbers of special frames is 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Depends if you want to count the one with `\frametitle{Special content}`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé My count goes like this: 2 frames within the environment + 1 which is created by it = 3

Comment: Indeed, it depends on how the count is done :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I present here a extended solution to [samcarter's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423475/18401) which works also in the case where several occurrences of `specialcontents` environment are to be used (and, say, this environment is not ours but given by a third party package or class -- in my real use case, it comes from the `versions` package).

The tricky problem was, when defining many "total counters" on the fly, [only the last one was created](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245113/18401). Thanks to the [egreg's trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245125/18401), the following is working like a charm:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{totcount}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\newenvironment{specialcontent}{%
}{%
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{specialcontent}{%
  \stepcounter{specialcontent@cntr}%
  %
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\newtotcounter{startspecial@\roman{specialcontent@cntr}}
    \noexpand\newtotcounter{endspecial@\roman{specialcontent@cntr}}%
  }\x
  %
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Special content (begins)}
    %
    \setcounter{startspecial@\roman{specialcontent@cntr}}{\totvalue{endspecial@\roman{specialcontent@cntr}}}%
    \addtocounter{startspecial@\roman{specialcontent@cntr}}{-\insertframenumber}%
    %
    The following special content:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \alert{has \total{startspecial@\roman{specialcontent@cntr}} frames},
    \item \alert{ends frame \total{endspecial@\roman{specialcontent@cntr}}}.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
}

\AtEndEnvironment{specialcontent}{%
  \setcounter{endspecial@\roman{specialcontent@cntr}}{\insertframenumber}%
}

\newcounter{specialcontent@cntr}%

\begin{document}

\multido{\i=1+1}{17}{%
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Foo bar}
    Foo\pause{} bar.
  \end{frame}
  %
  \section{Special \i{}}
  %
  \begin{specialcontent}
    \multido{\I=1+1}{\i}{%
      \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Foo bar (special content)}
        Foo\pause{} bar.
      \end{frame}
    }
  \end{specialcontent}
  %
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Foo bar}
    Foo\pause{} bar.
  \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]